# Getting null when calling AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() after restarting the app

Tags: javascript, react-native, facebook-javascript-sdk, react-native-ios, react-native-fbsdk

I want accessToken in componentDidMount but getting null in the promise response when I restart (not reload) the app. I think that FBSDK login is not persisting the accessToken in the app. This only happens in iOS (Both: real device and simulator) and in Android, it works fine.

1. Login into the app
2. Calling AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() after login success (Note: I'm getting accessToken two times) after login (it works well) in the componentDidMount (I'm getting null even after login)
3. After Login, I close & reopen (not reloading: in reloading the app, I'm getting the accessToken) the app (to invoke componentDidMount) but getting null in promise response.

Code:

```
  const _checkFbAccessToken = async () => {
    try {
      const { accessToken } = await AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
      console.log(accessToken, ' ****accessToken');
    } catch (error) {
      // error in getting accessToken 
    }
  };
```

Environment:

```
System:
    OS: macOS 10.15.1
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4980HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
    Memory: 11.27 GB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
  Binaries:
    Node: 11.12.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.15.2 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.7.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 25, 26, 27, 28
      Build Tools: 28.0.2, 28.0.3
      System Images: android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 3.3 AI-182.5107.16.33.5314842
    Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  npmPackages:
    react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6 
    react-native: 0.60.5 => 0.60.5 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```